# Equivalence of two topological conditions

Tags: general-topology

Are the following two conditions on a topological space $X$ equivalent?

1) $X$ is Hausdorff, second countable, and locally Euclidean.
2) $X$ is Hausdorff, second countable, and locally compact.

I know that 1) implies 2), what about the converse and is there any theorem about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another counter example.  A countable discete space.

Comment: Many definitions of "locally Euclidean" allow for spaces in which points have open neighborhoods homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^0$, the single-point space (i.e., discrete spaces). So whether this answer is correct depends on whether $\mathbb{R}^0$ is permitted as a "Euclidean space". (For what it is worth, I have been unable to find a reference that explicitly excludes this, but have found some that explicitly allow it.)

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: in $\mathbb{R}^2=\{(x,y)|x,y\in \mathbb{R}\}$, consider $\{(x,0)\}\cup \{(0,y)\}$. It is Hausdorff, second countable, locally compact, but not locally Euclidean. To be specific, $(0,0)\in X$ has no open neighborhood isomorphic to Euclidean space.